# Remove filter's label in Backpack for Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

Does someone know in which file exactly can I delete the filter result label at the list view?
For example, say that I have a list of teams, and in each team, I also have a list of users. I want to filter out the users that are not inside the team's menu that I'm visiting right now. So i use **$this->crud->addClause()** method provided by Backpack. What I don't want is that after the filter has run, it shows me the **Showing 1 to 1 of 1 entry (filtered from 4 total entries). Reset** label. Of course, I don't want my user to know how many users I'm having inside my DB(you can see it from the **filtered from 4 total entries** label), that's why I want to remove that label. Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks. By the way, here's the label located :

[List of users view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdXWf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could hide it using something like:

```
@push('after_scripts')
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".dataTables_info").hide()});
</script>
@endpush
```

add the previous code to the end of your
resources/views/vendor/backpack/base/inc/topbar_right_content.blade.php file

it will hide the overall statistics ..

Answer (score 1):

Internally, Backpack use [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) for CRUDs list operations.
Looking at DataTable's documentation, there's an option to disable the records count / filtered records [info](https://datatables.net/reference/option/info).

Backpack's DataTable is setup in **datatables_logic.blade.php** which is located at **/vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/crud/inc**

If a blade file with the exact name exists in resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud folder, Backpack will pick up that instead, so all you have to do is

1. Copy the original datatables_logic.blade.php into **WhateverYourAppNameIs/resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/inc/datatables_logic.blade.php**
2. Edit the file & locate this (around line 88)

   ```
     dataTableConfiguration: {         
     @if ($crud->getResponsiveTable())
   ```

And change it into this

```
      dataTableConfiguration: {         
      "info": false,
      @if ($crud->getResponsiveTable())
```

That's it. Filtered records count is gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide the **filtered from 4 total entries label**

Do what @rbndeveloper had mention to copy the `datatables_logic.blade.php`

Inside the file do the below changes.

go to

```
"infoFiltered":   "{{ trans('backpack::crud.infoFiltered') }}",
```

change to

```
"infoFiltered":   "",
```

You have to the total record removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the ListOperation::search() method in your EntityCrudController and change like this: 
Instead of

```
$totalRows = $this->crud->model->count();
```

Write

```
$totalRows = $this->crud->count();
```

Now you'll only see the line

> "Showing x to x of x entries"

.
 and

> "filtered from x total entries"

will be removed now because the total records are equal to the fetched records.

Answer (score 0):

Open **list.php** from **/config/backpack/operations/list.php**

To remove the count set *showEntryCount* to *false*

```
'showEntryCount' => false,
```

To remove the reset button set *resetButton* to *false*

```
'resetButton' => false,
```